# Test method attempts Email Alert from Flow and fails with NO_SINGLE_MAIL_PERMISSION in sandbox

Tags: visual-workflow, test-automation

We have a Flow that sends an Email Alert. We have a test method that unintentionally exercises that flow. The test method fails.

I know already that NO_SINGLE_MAIL_PERMISSION is thrown because our sandbox has Deliverability Access Level set to "System email only". We prefer it that way. When necessary we temporarily change it to "All email" for a brief window and then put it back.

We've encountered this same error many time with our Apex code. We workaround it easily by adding a check of `Test.isRunningTest`. I want to do something similar with Flows. I do not think `Test.isRunningTest` or `Quiddity` is available from Flow--although I would be happy to be wrong.

We are encouraging our team to build in Flows instead of Apex where convenient so we will start encountering this issue more often.

How have others solved this problem?

I'm thinking about exposing `Test.isRunningTest` or `Quiddity` from an `@InvocableMethod` so we can incorporate that into a decision and bypass the Email Alert in the flow.

Comment: [Pass a 'test=true` variable](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_internal_url_variable.htm&type=5) to the flow.

Comment: If using System.runAs(user) in testmethods, you could assign a custom permission to that user and then check presence of that permission in the Flow before sending the email